# VBA: How to change a blank value returned using a Vlookup into a Space " "

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using VBA to Vlookup information from one table into another.  The information that I'm trying to return for Column I is only available for some of the rows.  The reference number is found, but the column where the information is being pulled from is blank.  Is there a way to turn these blank returns into a space " " with VBA.  Again, I have more code relying on these blanks to show as spaces: Any help would be appreciated.  This is what I used to try to turn them into blanks that did not work:

```
Sub Macro10 ()

Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

Range("I5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C[-7],Sheet1!C4:C13,4,0),"" "")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I5:I" & Lastrow)

End Sub
```

Comment: What about using `ISBLANK`: `"=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(C[-7],Sheet1!C4:C13,4,0)),"" "", VLOOKUP(C[-7],Sheet1!C4:C13,4,0)),"" "")"`

Comment: thanks for the reply.  The problem is that, the value that is being pulled from the Vlookup is not a space " " it is just a blank ""

Comment: I understand that, that is why I proposed `ISBLANK` which tests for an empty value, not for a space.

Comment: I tried the code and it did not work.  The answer provided by Max worked perfectly.  I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C[-7],Tabelle1!C4:C13,4,0),"" "")="""","" "",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C[-7],Tabelle1!C4:C13,4,0),"" ""))"
```

Comment: You're the best Max, thanks so much.  This worked perfectly.